# Named groups with slashes in Django URLs

Tags: python, regex, django, url

I have a set of following URLs defined:

```
GET /data/(?P<tag>[^/]+)$
POST /data/(?P<tag>[^/]+)/action_1$
POST /data/(?P<tag>[^/]+)/action_2$
...
```

I would like to know whether it is possible to use tags containing slashes?

E.g., when I try to get the data for the tag `a/b/c`, I always obtain 404 errors. Although I quote tags before forming actual URLs (i.e. `/data/a%2Fb%2Fc` for the previous case), the obtained URLs still do not match (though `a%2Fb%2Fc` should match `[^/]+`), because it looks like Django performs implicit unquoting, which is undesired. How can I overcome this problem without changing the URL forming scheme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slash is a slash, whether it's quoted or not. That's how it's defined in the RFC, and that's how Django (correctly) handles it. A webserver should not differentiate between quoted and unquoted entities in the url path, unless the unquoted entity is a reserved character with a specific meaning.

What you can do is put the more specific urls first. Django always uses the first matching url, so that way a call ending in `/action_1` or `/action_2` will be routed to the more specific url, and everything else falls back to the more general url. Then you can change the capture group to accept slashes:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^data/(?P<tag>.+)/action_1$', action1_view),
    url(r'^data/(?P<tag>.+)/action_2$', action2_view),
    url(r'^data/(?P<tag>.+)$', general_view),
]
```

Comment: Perfect, that is exactly what I need! Thank you very much.